# Cannot edit cells in ag grid pivot table enabled

Tags: reactjs, dataframe, ag-grid

I am using the pivot mode of ag-Grid, and I am unable to edit the cells when passing 'editable': true in the defaultColDef. However, it's working if I am not using the pivot mode. What am I doing wrong here, or is there any way to edit the cells in ag-Grid when pivot mode is enabled?.

```
defaultColDef = {
editable: true
}
```

I attempted to enable cell editing in pivot mode but failed in doing so. I am seeking a way to edit cells with pivot mode enabled using ag-Grid.

Comment: You cannot edit in pivot mode because the values are calculated (e.g. sum, avg etc.); you're not viewing the actual data, but calculated fields.